# setting the color of a stacked bar (google charts)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Using google charts I'm trying to customise the color of certain sections on [this](http://puu.sh/gUzsw/44f0cf0fa2.png) stacked bar

```
$(function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', { 'callback': drawChart, 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Grade', 'NG (% of total Results)', 'F (% of total Results)', 'E (% of total Results)', 'D3 (% of total Results)',
                   'D2(% of total Results)', 'D1 (% of total Results)','C3 (% of total Results)','C2 (% of total Results)','C1 (% of total Results)', 'B3 (% of total Results)','B2 (% of total Results)', 'B1 (% of total Results)','A2 (% of total Results)', 'A1 (% of total Results)',  { role: 'annotation' } ],
                  ["English", 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,5, 5,5 ,35, ''],                   //use german[2] index of variables for each percent
                  ["Maths", 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,5, 5,20 ,20, '']
                ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                var options = {
                  width: 600,
                  height: 400,
                  legend: { position: 'none'},
                  bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
                  colors: ['#dfdfdf','#d4d4d4','#d2d2d2','#d8d8d8','#e3e3e3','#d4d4d4','#dcdcdc','d7d7d7','dadada','d9d9d9','d6d6d6'],
                  isStacked: true,
                  hAxis: { 
                        viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                        viewWindow: {
                            max:101,
                            min:0
                        }
                    },
                 chartArea: {'height': '90%'}
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
                chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

I want to change the color of one section on each bar, for example the 35 value on English and the last 20 value on Maths. I cannot hard-code it in with a style role column as the value I need to color changes based on user info. I've attempted various ways along the lines of the following to no avail. Thank you.

```
data.setProperty(0,0,{                          
    type: "string",
    role: "style" }, 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you have 14 different series and 2 rows.
If you try to style by series using something like `series: { 4: { color: "blue"}}` you'll change the color of that series for both rows.

If you try to add a new column to the data for styling like this:

```
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Grade', 'NG (% of total Results)', 'F (% of total Results)', 'E (% of total Results)', 'D3 (% of total Results)',
               'D2(% of total Results)', 'D1 (% of total Results)','C3 (% of total Results)','C2 (% of total Results)','C1 (% of total Results)', 'B3 (% of total Results)','B2 (% of total Results)', 'B1 (% of total Results)','A2 (% of total Results)', 'A1 (% of total Results)',  { role: 'annotation' }, {type: 'string', role: 'style'} ],
            ["English", 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,5, 5,5 ,35, '', 'color: #cfc'],                   //use german[2] index of variables for each percent
            ["Maths", 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,5, 5,20 ,20, '', 'color: #0f0']
            ]);

        data.setCell(1,16, "color: red");
```

you'll only be able to set the style for that row without control over which column.

[image: Output]

Neither one of these is really what you want.  My instinct here is that the data isn't actually formatted in a way that will work for this but I don't have any ideas at the moment.  I figured I'd show you what I can do and maybe it will be enough to get you on the right track even if I can't see what that is.